# Class number of non-maximal order in imaginary quadratic function field?

Tags: nt.number-theory

It is well known that for $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$, $D < 0$, the non-maximal order of squarefree conductor $f$, relatively prime to $D$, has class number $$h_K \prod_{p|f} (p-(\frac{D}{p}))$$

What is the class number of a non-maximal order in an imaginary quadratic extension of $\mathbb{F}_p[t]$? Is it proven using ideas involving zeta function, as appears in many books for the case above?

Comment: EGA IV$_4$, 2nd line of (21.8.5.1).

Comment: So practically the same thing... Thanks!

Comment: I was actually looking for a proof of the original fact you quoted, and Googling led me here... would you please provide a reference? Thank you!

Comment: p.s. Please, I beg you, not EGA.

Comment: Harvey Cohn's Advanced Number Theory, chapter 13, section 2, theorem 2 (Dover edition, pp. 217).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a formula that works in all degrees, not just imaginary quadratic.  In a global field $K$, let $O$ be integral over ${\mathbf Z}$ or ${\mathbf F}[t]$ (${\mathbf F}$ a finite field) and be "big", i.e., it has fraction field $K$.  Let $\mathfrak c$ be the conductor ideal of $O$ in its integral closure $R$.  Then 
$$h(O) = \frac{h(R)}{[R^\times:O^\times]}\frac{\varphi_{R}({\mathfrak c})}{\varphi_O(\mathfrak c)},$$
where $\varphi_O(\mathfrak c)$ is the number of units in $O/\mathfrak c$ and $\varphi_R(\mathfrak c)$ is the number of units in $R/\mathfrak c$.  This is derived in Neukirch's alg. number theory book in the number field case, but it goes through to any one-dimensional Noetherian domain with a finite residue rings and a finite class group.
In the imag. quadratic case the unit index $[R^\times:O^\times]$ is 1 most of the time so you don't notice it.

Both $\varphi_R(\mathfrak c)$ and $\varphi_O(\mathfrak c)$ can be written in the form ${\text N}(\mathfrak c)\prod_{\mathfrak p \supset \mathfrak c}(1 - 1/{\text{N}(\mathfrak p)})$, where the ideal norm $\text N$ means the index in $R$ or $O$ and $\mathfrak p$ runs over primes in $R$ or $O$ for the two cases.